# DisplayName attribute for Interface

Tags: interface, attributes

Is there an alternative way to change the display name of an interface?
Compiler tells the DisplayName attribute is only valid for class

```
[DisplayName("Employee")]  <- issue with this
interface IPerson
{   ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `DisplayNameAttribute` has `AttributeTargets` of `Class | Method | Property | Event`, and so disables the use being applied to an interface.
Likely there's no particular design reason, it was just never needed so never considered.

The simplest solution would be to extend the attribute and apply your own `AttributeTargets`.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface | AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Event)]
public class MyDisplayNameAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public MyDisplayNameAttribute(string name) : base (name) { }
}

[MyDisplayName("NewName")]
interface IMyInterface { }
```

The nice effect of this approach is that you can then retrieve it like a "normal" `DisplayNameAttribute`:

```cs
var attrs = typeof(IMyInterface).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

No attributes can not be applied to interfaces. Here's a list of the valid attribute targets

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/#attribute-targets

You could instead create an abstract class in which all members are abstract. This, to some level, would be the same as an interface with an attribute. But using an abstract class in place of an interface has other implications that affect the architecture of your application.

Comment: This is incorrect, I'm not sure why that document is so incorrect (even the capitalisation is wrong), but `Interface` (1024) has been in the `AttributeTarget` enum since .NET Framework 1.1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attributetargets?view=netframework-1.1

This works fine:  
`[Obsolete] interface IWithAttribute { }`  
`var attrs = typeof(IWithAttribute).GetCustomAttributes(false);`  
`Console.WriteLine(attrs[0].GetType().Name); // Gives: ObsoleteAttribute`